# Можно ли из PreferenceScreen вызывать активити

Tags: android

Можно ли из экрана настроек PreferenceScreen вызвать окно активити для особенных настроек? Потому что из пунктов типа ListPreference активити вызвать нельзя. Можно создать своё активити для настроек, но у меня в настройках требуются и ListPreference, CheckBoxPreference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте просто `Preference` будет как обычная кнопка. Ну а потом выполняйте

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, TurboActivity.class));
```

при клике на ней